# Getting a strange NumberFormatException while trying to parse a string to an int

Tags: java, runtime-error, numberformatexception

I am getting the following exception - Kindly advise

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
```

There seem to be no whitespaces as you can see "2". I just split a string and get "2" as one of the elements of the split array then I get this while trying to parse it into an int

Kindly advise

Comment: can you post your code? but i think that is " "

Comment: What's the string's length?  If its length is 3 then you've probably got quotes in the string, i.e. your string is ""2""

Comment: show some code please..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please post your code. beacuse if exception is

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
```

this means your String say s is 2 not "2"
and for "2" you cann't use

```
Integer myInt = Integer.parseInt(" \"2\" ");
```

This will any way give you Number format exception. Because you cann't part string to it, only number is parse using `Integer.parseIn()` and "2" is String.

Comment: My code is as simple as this - 
String rev = document.getRevision();
  int version = rev == null ? 1 : Integer.parseInt(rev.split("-")[0]) + 1;

Comment: Can you please send me the value of document.getRevision(); i checked with rev as rev = "2" and it works fine on my machine.

Comment: its 2-bd7e03c95c6cea9bb4a665333c84512c .. .it works when i parse it directly but not when i fetch from document and parse .. strange

Comment: yes i run code using rev = "2-bd7e03c95c6cea9bb4a665333c84512c" it works fine. So don't know why you face this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether string is 2 or "2" 
if 2 then use

```
Integer myInt = Integer.parseInt("2");
```

if "2" then trip and then apply `Integer.parseInt();`

Answer (score 0):

You are passing  " " you sure have a double quote like

```
Integer myInt = Integer.parseInt(" \"2\" ");
```

Just use

`Integer myInt = Integer.parseInt("2");`

Your problem is in this part of Integer class you can debug it

`digit = Character.digit(s.charAt(i++),radix);`

Comment: Integer myInt = Integer.parseInt(" \"2\" "); run this line on your system. It will give you an exception.

Comment: @AshishAggarwal yes i know it, i post that cuase is the problem that he has.. may be i was not clear in my answer i edited

Comment: @nachook my concern is just that before posting anything on SO we all must have to run same on our machine(if possible)

Comment: You dont understand i already know that gives an exception.. i explain why he has that..